# Joda Time to Date in the specified format

Tags: java, jodatime

I have a DateTime(joda date) object in the form 2015-09-04T17:08:09. I need to convert it into the format EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z yyyy such  such that after converting I get a Date object in this format. Can someone please guide. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not possible.

Joda `DateTime` objects and `java.util.Date` objects do not have a format by themselves. There is no such thing as a `DateTime` or `Date` object in some particular format.

`DateTime` and `Date` objects just contain date and time information, and do not contain information on how to display the date and time information.

To display a `DateTime` in a particular format, you create a `DateTimeFormatter` object. You specify on that object how you want the `DateTime` to be formatted - the `DateTimeFormatter` is what contains the format information, not the `DateTime` object itself.

When using `java.util.Date`, you use a `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

You have a joda `DateTime` object.  It's in an internal form, and both the representation you show and the representation you desire are formatted `String` representations.

You don't really need to convert your date into another date, but format it as a String.

For that, you need a [DateTimeFormatter](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html).  You can produce an appropriate one by calling a factory method in [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

```
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z yyyy");
 String str = fmt.print(dt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link to Joda formatting: [Joda Formatting](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/key_format.html)